# OpenGL warning after calling glCopyNamedBufferSubData and glNamedBufferSubData

Tags: opengl, opengl-4

I'm getting the following warning:

`Buffer performance warning: Buffer object 19 (bound to NONE, usage hint is GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW) is being copied/moved from VIDEO memory to HOST memory`.

I allocate this buffer with `glNamedBufferStorage`. I copy data into it from another buffer (allocated the same way) with `glCopyNamedBufferSubData` then update some of its data with `glNamedBufferSubData`. this gives me an warning. I don't use mapping. Just these functions. (Using OpenGL4.5. Card is NVidia.)

So far I couldn't reproduce this warning with some minimal code but it comes consistently. After searching I found people who got this message used some kind of buffer mapping. What can cause this warning in my case? How can I found more about what is causing it?

EDIT:

Minimal reproducible example:

```
GLuint test_buffer_1_ID;
GLuint test_buffer_2_ID;

glCreateBuffers(1, &test_buffer_1_ID);
glCreateBuffers(1, &test_buffer_2_ID);

UByte data_source[100];

const GLbitfield flags = GL_DYNAMIC_STORAGE_BIT;

glNamedBufferStorage(test_buffer_1_ID, 100, data_source, flags);
glNamedBufferStorage(test_buffer_2_ID, 100, data_source, flags);

glCopyNamedBufferSubData(
    test_buffer_1_ID,
    test_buffer_2_ID,
    0,
    0,
    10
);

glNamedBufferSubData(
    test_buffer_2_ID,
    0,
    10,
    data_source
);
```

Warning comes when `glNamedBufferSubData` is called. If I specify source data `glNamedBufferStorage` or give it `nullptr` makes no difference. If I call SubData first and Copy after, or just SubData, then there is no warning.

Answer (score 3):

Because people have misused and mischaracterized buffer objects so frequently in the past, implementers have basically been forced to move buffer storage around based on how it is *used*, not how you say it will be used.

You said that your buffer would be filled by the CPU (otherwise you couldn't use BufferSubData on it). But if you drop stuff in it from the CPU enough times, the driver will think that you're *serious* about doing that. So it will move the storage to directly CPU-accessible memory, where such copies will be cheaper. Potentially at the cost of read performance.

If you're updating the storage of the buffer so frequently that you're triggering this condition, it might be better to just map it persistently and write to that when you need to. Of course, you'll now have to manage synchronization, but you should have been doing that anyway if performance mattered to you.

Comment: Thank you! Unfortunately the case is that I do about 1 copy-from-buffer and 1 sub-data call. I tried to debug it, if it is only the copy from other buffer or only the sub-data call, then it is fine. The trigger is when I call buffer-sub-data after copy.

Comment: I made edit with minimal reproducible example. If you have some time please take a look at it.